# How to make Slack Bot not respond to all the messages in the private group?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I want my bot to respond only if anyone mentions its name like **@mybot**.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make slackbot reply if the message starts only with a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878765/how-to-make-slackbot-reply-if-the-message-starts-only-with-a-tag)

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864731/slack-event-api-for-bot-mentions/41875457#41875457

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events) and subscribe to the event [`app_metion`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention).

That way your app will receive all message that directly mention your bot with @mybot.

Those messages will be sent as request from Slack to the endpoint provided for receiving events.